# Div not auto resizing height when elements are revealed from display none

Tags: html, css

I am a little confused with my current project, I am trying to make drop-down lists in the footer. However, I seem to be unable too auto resize the parent footer container when the event occurs to remove display none from the nested UL element. I am super baffled because in my nav I can set the UL items to height 0 and then transition the height but on this footer UL I am unable to do the same.

I have hosted the site here:

[Aquatics Site](https://evilernie44.github.io/sma/)

I could copy paste the code however this seems easier.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: [mcve] means that it only includes the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem. Going through the entire site is too much work. Also nobody wants to click links outside, no way of knowing what it contains.

Comment: I could but I immediately fixed the error after posting ill close now, thanks.

Comment: I had created a bug earlier on which conflicted with my nav ul and footer ul.

Comment: Actually it is expanding, but is not scrolling up i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.fa-sort-down').click(function(){ $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }); });});
```

Add this code to js and check.

Comment: Not what Iw as after but I do intend to do this anyway thanks.